# Login with FB button Framework7

Tags: facebook-login, html-framework-7

im having a problem on implementing the login FB on my framework7 code. It just doesnt display the button, as follows:

```
<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
      <div class="content-block">
        <p>Left panel content goes here</p>
        <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
        </fb:login-button>
        <button class="btn-default" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Login fb</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any sugestion on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your project is in cordova environment ? , I would suggest You using cordova fb plugin
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Mine work like a charm

1. Login page

   ```
                       <li class="item-link">
                           <a class="signin button button-raised">Sign In</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="item-link">
                           <a class="registerpage button button-raised">Register</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="item-link">                                
                           <span id="facebookLogin" class="button button-fill color-blue">Login With Facebook</span>                                                                
                       </li>
                       <li class="item-link">
                           <span id="googleLogin" class="button button-fill color-red">Login With Google</span>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
   ```
2. init function

   $('#facebookLogin').on('click', function () {
               facebookLogin();
           })
3. facebookLogin function

   ```
   function facebookLogin() {        
      facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_hometown", "email"],
       fbLoginSuccess,
       function (error) { app.app.alert(JSON.stringify(error)) }
   );

    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {      
      // use token from userData to your existing login system
      //userData.authResponse.accessToken 
     };

   }
   ```

Comment: I'm still not putting on phone gap, but I'll certainly do that. Thanks man

Comment: glad if it can help